# How can I append a div into another by ussing "append to this"?

Tags: jquery

So, I have 3 different divs, each has an edit button. Currently, when you click the edit button the page scrolls all the way down. So, what I am trying to do is that when you click on edit, it appends the edit box below the edit button that is clicked.

So this is my code.

```
<div class="sandbox" id="orange_sandbox">
   <span class="edit">Edit</span>

</div>
<div class="sandbox" id="blue_sandbox">
   <span class="edit">Edit</span>

</div>
<div class="sandbox" id="green_sandbox">
   <span class="edit">Edit</span>

</div>

<div class="kittens">
   The form will go here
</div>

<script>
   $('.edit').on('click', function(){
      $('.kittens').appendTo("this");  
   });
</script>
```

I can't get it to work. I don't think it should be appended to a parent because those divs are not related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.edit').on('click', function(){
      $(this).after($('.kittens'));  
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sandbox" id="orange_sandbox">
   <span class="edit">Edit</span>

</div>
<div class="sandbox" id="blue_sandbox">
   <span class="edit">Edit</span>

</div>
<div class="sandbox" id="green_sandbox">
   <span class="edit">Edit</span>

</div>

<div class="kittens">
   The form will go here
</div>
```

1. Use `this` context.
2. Use [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: This is very interesting. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. Just make small modification as `$('.kittens').appendTo(this);` to your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.edit').on('click', function() {
    $('.kittens').appendTo(this);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sandbox" id="orange_sandbox">
  <span class="edit">Edit</span>

</div>
<div class="sandbox" id="blue_sandbox">
  <span class="edit">Edit</span>

</div>
<div class="sandbox" id="green_sandbox">
  <span class="edit">Edit</span>

</div>

<div class="kittens">
  The form will go here
</div>
```